# Calling an operator from a namespace in R

Tags: r, namespaces, package, zoo

I am developing a package, which depends on `zoo` (listed in `Imports`, not `Depends` in `DESCRIPTION`).

In a function, I need to subset two-dimensional `zoo` object by `[` operator. However, as long as `zoo` package is not loaded, R uses base `[`, which returns `numeric` instead of `zoo`.

A standard solution would be to use a namespace of `zoo` (like `` zoo::`[.zoo`() ``). However, when I try to execute this in the function R throws an error `Error: '[.zoo' is not an exported object from 'namespace:zoo'`, so I conclude that this operator is not exported in `zoo` namespace (even though I could see it in https://github.com/rforge/zoo/blob/master/pkg/zoo/NAMESPACE).

Solution 1: It is possible to use `:::` operator to use a non-exported function from a package. Probably it is not a best practice.

Solution 2: I can create a new `zoo` using `coredata` and `index`, which are explicitly exported, i.e.:

`zoo_new <- zoo::zoo(x = zoo::coredata(zoo_old), order.by = zoo::index(zoo_old))`

which is not very elegant.

Solution 3: Move `zoo` from `Imports` to `Depends` in `DESCRIPTION`. Also it is not the best practice.

Comment: Did you try adding `importFrom(zoo,"[")` to your namespace file (or `importFrom(zoo,"[.zoo")`) ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper nope, because I use `roxygen2` generated NAMESPACE

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right, using `:::` is not best practice and not allowed for CRAN packages. According to this post http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/depends.html you should either contact the authors of zoo or use the code of their function directly inside your package.

Comment: I have chosen the second solution: i.e. creating a new object: `zoo_new <- zoo::zoo(x = zoo::coredata(zoo_old)[1:2], order.by = zoo::index(zoo_old)[1:2])`